# Enabled export isn't shown on DevExtreme dxChart

Tags: javascript, charts, export, devexpress, devextreme

Hi there I've got follow chart:

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  var dataSource = [
        {
            argument: '15.06.2016',
            puls: 102,
            temperatur: 37.6,
            weight: 91
        },
        {
            argument: '16.06.2016',
            puls: 99,
            temperatur: 35.1,
            weight: 88
        },
        {
            argument: '17.06.2016',
            puls: 87,
            temperatur: 38.0,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '18.06.2016',
            puls: 91,
            temperatur: 36.3,
            weight: 87
        },
        {
            argument: '19.06.2016',
            puls: 112,
            temperatur: 37.1,
            weight: 90
        }
    ];

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            type: "spline",
            label: {
                visible: false,
                connector: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            argumentField: "argument",
            axis: "pulsAxe"
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            customizeTooltip: function(obj) {
                if (obj.seriesName == "Puls") {
                    return {
                        text: obj.value + " bpm"
                    }
                } else if (obj.seriesName == "Gewicht") {
                    return {
                        text: obj.value + " kg"
                    }
                } else if (obj.seriesName == "Temperatur") {
                    return {
                        text: obj.value + " °C"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            verticalAlignment: "top",
            horizontalAlignment: "right"
        },
        title: {
            text: "Hugo Amacher | 15.08.1977 (M)",
            subtitle: {
                enabled: true,
                text: "Ich bin ein Untertitel..."
            }
        },
        export: {
            enabled: true,
            printingEnabled: true
        },
        zoomingMode: "all",
        series: [
            {
                name: "Puls",
                valueField: "puls"
            },
            {
                name: "Temperatur",
                valueField: "temperatur",
                axis: "temperaturAxe"
            },
            {
                name: "Gewicht",
                valueField: "weight",
                axis: "weightAxe"
            }
        ],
        valueAxis: [
            {
                name: "pulsAxe",
                title: "Puls",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " bpm"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "temperaturAxe",
                title: "Temperatur",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " °C"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "weightAxe",
                title: "Gewicht",
                position: "left",
                label: {
                    customizeText: function(value) {
                        return value.value + " kg"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>DevExtreme Chart</title>
        <!--FRAMEWORK-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.5/js/dx.chartjs.js"></script>
        <!--JS-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartContainer" style="width:100%; height: 440px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to enable the export-dropdown I've sawn many times in dxCharts (export to pdf, png etc.). I followed the instructions of the API: http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/export/?version=16_1

My code for enabling export:

```
export: {
    enabled: true,
    printingEnabled: true
},
```

But there is no dropdown on the chart...How can I enable it or place it on my chart? Here is an example what I mean:

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Hi! What version of DevExtreme do you have? This client-side export is available only for new 16.1 version

Comment: Hi, I've gott the trial edition of devextreme 16.1.4... Cheers